# Selenium: Finding web element by text using xpath

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I need to find a web element by text. I have this xpath:

```
"/html/body/div/div[3]/div/table[2]/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[5]/td/div/div[2]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[5]/td/div/div[1]/div/ul/li"
```

The text I need to find is "next" and it is inside on of those li's. 
I try something like this

```
WebElement xnext = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(),'next')]"));
```

but it is not working. This is the what the html looks like:

```
<div class="listview-visible z-listbox">
    <div class="z-listbox-paging-top">
        <div class="z-paging z-paging-os">
            <ul> 
               <li> 1 </li>
               <li> 2 </li>
               <li> 3 </li>
               <li> Next </li>
               <li> Last </li>
            </ul>
         </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you consider updating us the relevant HTML DOM please? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with your xpath.

First, it's the li element that contains the text.
Second, the text is case sensitive.

Try this xpath:

```
//li[contains(text(),'Next')]
```

One tool that can help you with xpaths is the Firebug and FirePath addons for Firefox. Firebug will allow you to inspect elements and firepath can show you the xpath. The xpath may not be exactly what you're looking for but at least you can use the addon to test your xpaths.

Comment: I tried it but it didn't work. It gave me this error again: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: //li[contains(text(),'Next')]

Answer (score 0):

Try this below mentioned xpath. 
**Note:** Before execute this xpath, provide some wait for few seconds, so your driver may able to find the web-element.

```
//div[@class='z-paging z-paging-os']//li[contains(text(), 'Next')]
```

> OR

Try this below `xpath` using `indexing number`.

Try using `indexing` after end of the `xpath`. In above `html` your `Next` keyword is located with fourth position inside `<li>` tag so, use this below mentioned `xpath`

```
//div[@class='z-paging z-paging-os']//li[4]
```

**Just for Information:** If you want to locate `Last` keyword inside your `<li>` tag, then simply change the indexing number. your `last` keyword locate inside `html` on fifth position so your `xpath` for the `last` keyword as below.

```
//div[@class='z-paging z-paging-os']//li[5]
```

Comment: Have you try this answer?